# Can I get the date of the current view? (DHTMLX Scheduler)

Tags: javascript, date, scheduler, dhtmlx

When I load the web, the DHTMLX Scheduler load the view of current day (today). But, it's possible to get the date if I go to other past days?
For example:

Today = 02/05/2013

I go, using the left arrows, to show the events of 25/04/2013. Then, using javascript, can I get the date of 25/04/2013 to do something like reload the Scheduler to this date directly using scheduler.init("",date,"");?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try scheduler.getState method:

```
var date = scheduler.getState().date;
var minDate = scheduler.getState().min_date;
var maxDate = scheduler.getState().max_date;
```

here is related doc: [scheduler.getState](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxscheduler:api_method_dhtmlxscheduler_getstate)